# req.body nãp funciona no Express

Tags: node.js, post, express.js

Estou tentando ler parâmetros enviados via post, mas o express só mostra no console.log objetos vazio.

Esse aqui é o código

```
import * as jsonServer from 'json-server'
import {Express} from "express";
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as https from 'https'

const server: Express = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

// Set default middlewares (logger, static, cors and no-cache)
server.use(middlewares)


// To handle POST, PUT and PATCH you need to use a body-parser
// You can use the one used by JSON Server
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)

server.post('/login', (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log(req.body)
})
 // --
// Use default router
server.use(router)
const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./backend/keys/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('./backend/keys/key.pem')
}
https.createServer(options, server).listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running on https://localhost:3001')
})
```

Estou tentando via como objeto do Postman

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já tentou mudar no *postman* de "Text" para "JSON"?

Comment: Onde faço essa mudança?

Comment: Ah encontrei e recebi os parametros

Comment: vou postar como uma resposta

Comment: Beleza, valeu!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que está mandando um objeto `JSON` com *plain text*, precisa mudar essa opção no *Postman*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso vai resolver